# python compare tuples and dictionary

Tags: python

I have to compare two sets and find the differences in python:

```
>>> mysql_orders = ((50434L, 5901L), (50733L, 5901L))
>>> opera_orders = [{'orderId': 'WEB050434', 'accountId': '00T001'}, {'orderId': 'WEB050733', 'accountId': '00T001'}, {'orderId': 'DOC075185', 'accountId': '00T001'}, {'orderId': 'WEB081859', 'accountId': '00T001'}]
```

One is a list of tuples and the other a list of dictionaries where the first item in the list could be the `orederId` without the WEB / DOC prefix.

What is the correct way to find the missing orderId's that are not in mysql_orders list?

Comment: Absolutely zero effort made. Try to write the code yourself and post it in your question.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to include the required function output for your example data?

Comment: You are having orderId prefix `WEB/DOC` or ' WEB0/DOC0`? And your mysql_order ids seems to be of type Long. So how would you compare it ?

Comment: what about the leading 0? Is that always there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With regex to strip off Alphabets, provided that numbers always come later,

```
import re

mysql_orders = ((50434L, 5901L), (50733L, 5901L))

opera_orders = [{'orderId': 'WEB050434', 'accountId': '00T001'}, {'orderId': 'WEB050733', 'accountId': '00T001'}, {'orderId': 'DOC075185', 'accountId': '00T001'}, {'orderId': 'WEB081859', 'accountId': '00T001'}]

mysql_orders = [element for tupl in mysql_orders for element in tupl]

missing_order_ids = [opera_order['orderId'] for opera_order in opera_orders if long(re.split('\D+', opera_order['orderId'])[1]) not in mysql_orders]

print missing_order_ids
```

Answer (score 0):

If the letters may or may not be there but the leading 0 is always there you can use a set a strip:

```
from string import ascii_letters

st = set(str(a) for a,_ in mysql_orders)

missing = [d['orderId'] for d in opera_orders if not d['orderId'].strip(ascii_letters)[1:] in st]

print(missing)

['DOC075185', 'WEB081859']
```

If the prefix is always there just slice:

```
missing = [d['orderId'] for d in opera_orders if not d['orderId'][4:] in st]
```